# Why is the "You cannot delete this accepted answer' pop-up message not auto dismissing?

Tags: support, popup

Today I noticed, when you want to delete one of your own accepted answers, a pop up message is shown as **"You cannot delete this accepted answer"**:

[image]

Then I noticed that this pop up message is not auto dismissing. We need to click that close icon of the pop up message.

I have tried to check that this pop up messages will dismiss by itself or not (waited for more than 5 minutes to check and it's still visible).

But it not dismissing itself like other pop up messages (for example, pop display when we flag any answer).

Steps to reproduce:

> Try to delete one of accepted answers
>
> Then check the pop up message is dismissing by itself or not

Why is the behaviour of this pop up message different?

Comment: The reason this message sticks around is that it has always stuck around (7+ years) and I didn't give it much consideration when I transitioned it from the old error style to the new.  The messages come from the server so I'd have to audit if dismissing it is inappropriate for any of the scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

My theory<sup>1</sup> behind the way this works is that it isn't a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), rather it is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

In most<sup>2</sup> of the other scenarios where the popup disappears, you have other visual cues, therefore, the popup is not required to stick around, for example:

- When you flag a comment, a flag appears near it
- When you up-vote / down-vote your own post the respective icon doesn't highlight in the same way it does if you up-vote / down-vote content that isn't yours

However, when you try to delete your question with answers, there is nothing else to indicate *why* your deletion hasn't taken place and if the popup was to disappear, you might even miss it.

As such, this ensures the user is aware *why* they can't delete the actual post.

---

<sup>1</sup> Not factual, just my (logical?) opinion

<sup>2</sup> As far as I'm aware

Comment: I'm not sure you need a footnote to clarify what you mean by "my theory"...

Comment: @TylerH leaving no room for misunderstandings.